# When we add pwa app to homescreen. Do we get two service workers then for the same site one with browser and one with native app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web-push

So Suppose we have a pwa app say X. When we install that app on homescreen, do we get two service workers one on browser say chrome and one in the native app? How push notifications will work in such cases, do we have to get subscription for native app separately for sending push notification to service worker of native app. And will these notifications appear in app or on chrome browser?

**P.S By native app I mean pwa app installed on homescreen**

Comment: It should work normally... you have only 1 service worker in any case.

Comment: @collimarco so if i remove browser from the system, push notifications will not work? i.e service worker is only registered with the browser and not the app installed on os?

Comment: PWA always runs in browser, only you might load it in full screen when launched from home screen. If you remove the browser through which you have installed PWA, the PWA itself will removed or won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to home screen does not add a native app to your device or desktop. It's still using browser resources. There's one service worker and one push notifications flow.